# How can I tell if a weapon is one or two handed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim is there a way to tell if a sword is one or two handed without picking it up. I'm not a fan of two handed weapons and I don't want to pick them up just to drop them when I realize it's not one handed. Specially, I want to know about swords but the answer may apply to other weapons as well. Is there some icon I'm missing? Or is it just a matter of weight?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's generally a matter of weight and weapon type.

**One-handed weapons** include daggers, swords (*not* greatswords), war axes (*not* battle axes), and maces (*not* warhammers). These will generally max out at 20 weight (with maces being the heaviest)

**Two-handed weapons** include greatswords (*not* regular swords), battle axes, and warhammers. Most have over 20 weight, but greatswords can weigh a little less (~15 weight).

Jesse Cox of OMFGcata [also notes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3uiyYMvecM#t=4m29s) you can tell by the orientation of the weapon in the preview window:

- Two-handed weapons are tilted to the side
- One-handed weapons are shown vertically straight

Answer (score 1):

You can see whether a weapon requires two hands if you equip it - if it's a one handed weapon it will say (L) or (R) (depending on which hand you put it in) and on two handed weapons it will show (LR) - just like with some spells that need two hands to cast (because it's too powerful for one hand).