# What weapons in Skyrim are one-handed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if a weapon is one or two handed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35211/how-can-i-tell-if-a-weapon-is-one-or-two-handed)

I am forging some new weapons for myself, but I don't want to waste my hard earned resources on a two-handed weapon. (I am proficient in one-handed battle)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons):

- Swords
- Maces
- War Axes
- Daggers*

The material type will not affect whether or not its one or two handed.

(Note that daggers do not benefit from one-handed skill perks Armsman or Bladesman. But instead they benefit from the perks in the sneak tree, namely Backstab and Assassin's Blade. [Source](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1342463-complete-character-design-freedom-damage-resist-caps-and-ridiculous-damage-thread-10/))

Finally, here are the two handed weapon types so you know which ones to avoid:

- Greatswords
- Warhammers
- Battleaxes

There are also Bows, which benefit from neither one handed perks and levels nor two handed perks and levels.